# Connecting to remote DB by default

Tags: mysql, linux

Hello I'm trying to connect by default to a remote mysql DB I have on a cpanel

I already gave access to the IP I'm trying to use to connect to the remote DB in the cpanel

I tried changing `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf`

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 189.251.13.63
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size         = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
```

After saving changes I went to `/etc/init.d/` and then did `mysqld restart`

Tried using `sudo mysql` and it keeps going to my localhost DB, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf` is the setting for the server. `mysql` is the command for the client. you must look for something called client.conf ... sorry I am on MariaDB and can't tell you more

Comment: `mysql` has a `--host` parameter to specify the remote server. You don't need to run `mysql` with `sudo`. Remote DB access for just administration should be done using ssh tunnel (port forward) rather than binding to a public IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `$HOME/.my.cnf` with following input:

```
[client] 
user=... 
host=...
port=...
```

`mysql` client should takes default connection parameters from this configuration file when you give no other option on the command line.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, this helped me out a lot!